# <div> or <canvas> for splitting a web page into two separate sections which are animated?

Tags: javascript, canvas, slider, html5-canvas

I am working on creating a page that will be split across the middle.

The page has content that is outside the viewing area on both the left and the right hand side. The idea is that when you click on one side of the page (say the left), an animation is triggered via JavaScript that pushes the content on the other side (the right in this case), hiding it.

The way I am designing it will be similar to this slider effect on the images on this page:
http://www.buzzfeed.com/alexnaidus/california-drought-images

The difference is that either side will have embedded within it other elements (divs, images, etc) and the animation is activated by **clicking** on either side rather than working automatically when scrolling over the area.

Now, what would the most semantically correct and easy to manage way of creating those two sections? (which act almost as layers): would you recommend working with divs and a JS or with the `<canvas>` element?

Many thanks!

Comment: As to what would be correct there is probably as many "correct" solutions as there are developers. You should try to rephrase the question as of now it may be off-topic. DOM/div and CSS/animations is what I personally would go for here.. Do you have some code you tried with and that got you into problems? If so please include this and we'll have a look. A fiddle/inline live demo would also help tremendously.